# Failing to upload artifact

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

This is my GitHub Actions workflow to upload the artifacts:

```
- name: List files
    working-directory: allure-raw
    run: |
      ls
- name: Upload artifact
    if: always()
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.3.0
    with:
      name: allure-raw
      path: ${{ github.workspace }}/allure-raw/
      retention-days: 10
```

but it's failing every time with error given below:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, realpath 'C:\actions-runner\_work\abc\repo\allure-raw\videos\rawSeleniumVideoGrabs\Validate-base-forecast-review-workflow-1--Edit-IBP-MAAS-Existing-DashBoard-and-Pivotcard-and-Load-with-new-dimension-Hiearachies-measures-and-apply-vertical-filter-BFR_TC1--CHROME--02-01-2024--07-20-08-794'
```

I also confirmed `allure-raw` folder exists. The Step list files gives the output as:

```
    Directory: C:\actions-runner\_work\abc\repo\allure-raw


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d-----        1/31/2024   8:47 PM                videos                                                                
-a----        1/31/2024   9:00 PM          18255 8a66b2d9-79dd-4887-b5a9-9cb6c6843e68-testsuite.xml
```

I am using Windows self-hosted runner with PowerShell.

Comment: The path length is 271. It looks like [this issue](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/240). Can you try before the upload `run: (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem").LongPathsEnabled`.

Comment: I am getting --

Run (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem").LongPathsEnabled
  (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem").LongPathsEnabled
  shell: C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  
0

Comment: Is it possible for you to shorten the name of the file?

Comment: actually, i shortened the file name and then tried..It worked

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a case of a path of a file to be included in the upload that exceded the windows maximum file path length, seen in [this issue](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/240).

Without setting the `HKLM:System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` registry key, the name must be short enough to be within the 256 character limit.